# Android - Recording voice call as separate tracks

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am trying to record to voice calls a separate tracks for caller & the responder.

I tried running these APIs in 2 services `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK` and `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK`

When I start a call these two services will start recording the call. Unfortunately, the 1st service is crashing (`IllegalStateException`) as the 2nd one is started. But, when I use only one of VOICE_UPLINK or VOICE_DOWNLINK, it is working perfectly fine.

What does it mean? Is it not possible to run two services of `MediaRecorder` at once?

I am just getting started with Android & got stuck here at the very first app.